# Not connecting to specific WiFi network

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

My Lenovo thinkpad (ubuntu 16.04 LTS) can't connect to a specific network. Other devices can connect to this network, and my laptop can also connect to other WiFi networks.

I had this same issue already some time ago on a different network and, if I remember well, fixed it with something similar to the answer in this thread: 
[Can't connect to specific wifi network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286915/cant-connect-to-specific-wifi-network)

I tried this and lots of other suggestions again but after trying for hours I've got no solution. Any ideas would be very much welcome.

Output of `lspci`:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)

08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
```

Output of `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
   *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 06
   serial: f0:de:f1:5b:36:ee
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:24 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff


*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: wlp8s0
   version: 00
   serial: 8c:a9:82:77:47:fc
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-34-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 ip=192.168.43.70 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
   resources: irq:28 memory:d1d00000-d1d01fff
```

Output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?